# Displaying Feature Info for a user defined polygon

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

To retrieve feature info for a polygon selection, I have the OpenLayers code below:

```
        var featureTypes  = ["nig_admin1", "nig_admin2", "nig_admin3", "nig_landscan"];
        var populationCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
            protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(nig_landscan, {
                url: "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: featureTypes
            }),
            hover: false
        });

        populationCtrl.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e){
            select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
```

I'd like to view the features retrieved in a pop up, or something similar. I've tried adding a pop up code within the `featureselected` event, but I can't get anything to show. Any pointers on how I can proceed will be highly appreciated.

`nig_landscan` in the code above refers to the corresponding WMS layer, which is a layer group in GeoServer.

My environment setup: GeoServer 2.1.3, PostGIS 1.5, OpenLayers 2.11.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: Sure @Sam007, I got something. I'll post it as an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WFS with filters, I was able to contruct a filter that retrieves info for the selection only. My code is as shown below:

```
select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection")
    selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(select, {
                clickout: false, toggle: false,
                multiple: false, hover: false,
                toggleKey: "ctrlKey", 
                multipleKey: "shiftKey", 
                box: true
            });
    map.addControl(selectCtrl);
    selectCtrl.activate();

    select.events.on({
        'beforefeatureadded': function(event) {

        },
        'featureselected': function(event) {
            var geometry900913 = event.feature.geometry;
            var geometry = geometry900913.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));

            var filter =  getGeometryFilter(getWkt(geometry)); 

            var wpsRequestData = getWPSRequestData(filter);
            sendWPSRequest(wpsRequestData);

            return false;
        },
        'featureunselected': function(feature) {

        }
    });

    map.addLayers([select]);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(select));
```

In this, I'm using WPS chained with WFS(with filter containing info about the selected geometry). From the code above, `getGeometryFilter(getWkt(geometry))` parses my geometry into WKT format, and constructs a valid filter. The filter is shown below:

```
function getGeometryFilter(polygon) {
    var filter =  
    '<ogc:Filter>' +
    '<ogc:Intersects>' +
        '<ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>' +
        '<ogc:Function name="collectGeometries">' +
         '<ogc:Function name="queryCollection">' +
            '<ogc:Literal>ws:layer_2</ogc:Literal>' +
            '<ogc:Literal>the_geom</ogc:Literal>' +
            '<ogc:Literal>INTERSECTS(the_geom,' + polygon + ')</ogc:Literal>' +
          '</ogc:Function>' +
        '</ogc:Function>' +
    '</ogc:Intersects>' +
    '</ogc:Filter>';

    return filter;
}
```

In my case, I was calculating population for the selected region. So, I constructed a `gs:Aggregate` request using the `WPS request builder`. I then passed the filter above to it. This is done in the `getWPSRequestData(filter)` method. This method is trivial if you use the WPS Request Builder.

My actual request is sent in the `sendWPSRequest(wpsRequestData);` function. Its details are shown below:

```
function sendWPSRequest(wpsRequestData) {
    var request = new OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: WPS_HOST,
        data: wpsRequestData,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=utf-8"
        },
        callback: function (response) {
            var gmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
            var xmlSum = gmlParser.read(response.responseText);
            parsePopulation(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("Something went wrong in the request");
        }
    });

}
```

I'm sending my request via POST, and using `OpenLayers.Format.GML` class to deal with the GML response.